# creating relationships VIA?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm reading packtpub asp.net social networking and I have problems with understanding following

"Here are the relationships that we need for the tables"

- Friends and Accounts via the owning account
- Friends and Accounts via the friends account
- ...

  What does really means? What type of relationship would you use?

  - Friends and Accounts via the owning account (many to one?)
  - Friends and Accounts via the friends account (ony to many?)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the book, but it means there are two similar relationships between the Friends table and the Account table, but different Friends columns are used in each relationship.

A friendship is a relationship between two accounts.  So two accounts need to be referenced by the Friends table.  As a simple example:

Accounts table:

- ID (Primary Key)
- Username

Friends table:

- Account1ID (Primary Key)
- Account2ID (Primary Key)

The Friends table uniquely represents a friendship between any two accounts.  To keep referential integrity, there needs to be two relationships between the Friends table and the Account table (as a foreign key):

- Friend.Account1 -> Account.ID
- Friend.Account2 -> Account.ID

One relationship for each account involved in the friendship.

Effectively the Friends table is the linking table in a many-to-many relationship, it's just that Accounts happens to be the table on both sides of the relationship.  It is a many-to-many relationship between an Account and another Account.